# Will Samsung Pay still work on the Gear S3 if you root your Galaxy phone?

Tags: rooting, samsung, custom-roms, samsung-knox

I currently own a Galaxy Note 7 which is running the stock ROM (from T-Mobile) and has *not* been rooted, yet.

The only major reason I have not rooted the device is that doing so will consequently block access to Samsung Pay, which is a sacrifice I am not willing to make. I understand why this restriction exists, but I still wish there was a way I could "have my cake and eat it too."

After looking at the teasers for the new Galaxy Gear 3, one of the things I noticed that piques my interest most is its support for Samsung Pay, but I am not entirely sure how it works.

A quick search seems to indicate that the Gear S2 model requires pairing with a Samsung phone to utilize it. However, with the Gear S3 now offering built-in LTE support, it can theoretically function fully with or without your phone on hand. In fact, this appears to be one of the new models major selling points.

So tl;dr: If I was to buy the Gear S3 and root my phone after, could I continue to utilize Samsung Pay on just the Gear itself without issues, or would this also block Samsung Pay from running on the Gear as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official web page... LTE watches work after an initial pairing with your smartphone & Samsung Pay works after initial set up with your phone and then you only get 5 payments with the watch without a phone before it needs to reconnect and re pair with your phone.

source: http://www.samsung.com/us/explore/gear-s3/?cid=ppc-

1* 4G LTE standalone connectivity only available on Samsung Gear S3 frontier version, a companion for compatible Android smartphones, sold separately. Standalone connectivity requires initial pairing of Gear S3 frontier with compatible phone and separate qualifying wireless plan. Standalone functionality limited if paired phone is not powered on or connected to a wireless network. Network coverage not available everywhere. Consult carrier for details.

2* Make up to five payments on your Gear S3 without a Galaxy smartphone nearby after initial setup. Reload payment capability by connecting to a Galaxy smartphone via Bluetooth. Only compatible with select cards, carriers and Samsung devices; see the Samsung Pay Support page http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/samsung-pay#compatibility for compatibility information.

Comment: Ah, I think that information may have just recently been added, than you! A bit unfortunate, I'm actually not really sure whether or not it's worth keeping Samsung Pay anymore. With things like the Xposed framework, the benefits of rooting seem to outweigh the usefulness of Samsung Pay. I might get an S3 watch anyways though, as it still does look quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have an S5 and a Gear S2 with Samsung Pay. While my S5 is not rooted, I cannot even get Samsung Pay for my S5. However, I'm using it with my Gear S2. So, I'm not sure how things will tie together, but I'd like to know this, as well. I want to get away from AT&T ROMs and load something custom. Simultaneously, I'd like to have Samsung Pay. Based on the fact that my current phone doesn't have the app, but the watch does, I think it might work with a rooted phone. The pairing and 5 payment limit refers to the watch communicating with the Gear App (and Samsung Pay portion of that) on your phone. It does not mean Samsung Pay on your watch needs to talk to a Samsung Pay app on your phone.